# Full path of selected file

Tags: angular, typescript, file

I need the full path of the file when user selects a file from Choose File using typeScript.
I tested some codes but i got only the name of the file.

`public onFileSelected(event: EventEmitter<File[]>) {
    const file: File = event[0];
    this.fileName = file.name;
}`

Comment: Why would you need the full path of the file ? [Be careful about XY problems](http://xyproblem.info). Also, consider reading [ask] and providing a [mcve] before posting a question.

Comment: are you trying to preview the  file selected?

Comment: Are you asking about a url or really a full path?

Comment: I want to send the url of selected file to the back-end 
url i mean the path of selected file from the pc (like D://file.pdf)

Comment: @AmalKallel that is not how you upload a file , you should send the file to the server and save the file at a folder in server then either  save the file name at the db or you could return the full path which can be used to retrieve the file

Answer (score 2):

You wont get full path as it would be security hole - leaking directory structure and potentially vulerable information (like user name for example)

Answer (score 0):

You will not get full path of selected file.Because it will always throw warning and will give fakepath.If you want to preview that particular file then there is a way to do that wihtout using full path of file.